# rewrite content length within a middleware

Tags: go

below code rewrites the http body response of some queries.

However, it fails to update the "content length" header field, it always remains the same original value.

How can i update the content length header field of the http response ?

```
type writeReplacer struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    search  []byte
    replace func(*http.Request) string
    buf     []byte
    r       *http.Request
    dir     string
}

func (w *writeReplacer) Write(in []byte) (int, error) {
    if w.buf == nil {
        w.buf = []byte{}
    }
    w.buf = append(w.buf, in...)
    n := len(in)
    if index := bytes.LastIndex(w.buf, w.search); index > -1 {
        var r []byte
        if w.dir == "before" {
            g := []byte(w.replace(w.r))
            n += len(g)
            r = append(g, w.buf[index:]...)
            w.buf = append(w.buf[:index], r...)
        } else {
            g := []byte(w.replace(w.r))
            n += len(g)
            r = append(r, w.buf[:index+len(w.search)]...)
            r = append(r, g...)
            r = append(r, w.buf[index:]...)
            w.buf = r
        }
    }
    return n, nil
}

func (w *writeReplacer) Flush() {
    w.ResponseWriter.Header().Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprint(len(w.buf)))
    w.ResponseWriter.Write(w.buf[:])
    w.buf = w.buf[:0]
}

func InsertAfter(h http.Handler, path string, search []byte, replace func(*http.Request) string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Path == path {
            w.Header().Del("Content-length")
            w = &writeReplacer{ResponseWriter: w, search: search, replace: replace, r: r, dir: "after"}
            defer w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func InsertBefore(h http.Handler, path string, search []byte, replace func(*http.Request) string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Path == path {
            w.Header().Del("Content-length")
            w = &writeReplacer{ResponseWriter: w, search: search, replace: replace, r: r, dir: "before"}
            defer w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

I receive two errors message, the first one from nginx

```
2019/03/08 05:58:37 [error] 31194#0: *19 
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, 
client: 82.21.18.16, server: buycoffee.online, request: 
"GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "buycoffee.online"
```

the second one from curl

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with 6237 bytes remaining to read
```

Comment: Is any of the handlers (`h`) calling `w.WriteHeader`? If so then that's your problem, and you can fix it by having your `*writeReplacer` implement that method as well and only keep track of the status code and then pass it to `ResponseWriter` during flush.

Comment: I have removed all the middlewares, except this one, to test. The error was still present. I also tried to delete Content-length and put a transfer-encoding chunked, but now net.http is complaining i use both of them, despite my deletion. I also tried to set the content length to -1, it did not work. I am about to dig more the solution your proposed, and to test different version of the language. thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mkopriva suggested the trick was to rewrite `ResponseWriter.WriteHeader`.

I believe it has to do with the fact that write might call writeheader at first call, and from there i was not putting the instructions at the right place.

in order to prevent further difficulties i prefer to use chunked transfer.

the code change is:

```
func (w *writeReplacer) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
    w.Header().Del("Content-length")
    w.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
    w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(statusCode)
}
```